# Why are there many zombie process in windows subsystem for linux(WSL)? How to kill them totally?

Tags: linux, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently, I find my WSL (ZSHELL) cost much CPU resource(around 35%) via the Windows resource manager.

Then I try to find out and solve this problem as follows:

```sh
  ~ ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Mar28 ?        00:00:00 /init ro
root         3     1  0 Mar28 tty1     00:00:00 /init ro
mbinary      4     3  0 Mar28 tty1     00:00:12 -zsh
mbinary     48     1  0 Mar28 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary     66     1  0 Mar28 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary    173     1  0 Mar29 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary    225     1  0 Mar29 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary    431     1  0 09:45 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
root      6845     1  0 09:53 tty2     00:00:00 /init ro
mbinary   6846  6845  0 09:53 tty2     00:00:04 -zsh
mbinary   7419  6846  0 10:03 tty2     00:00:00 python3
mbinary   7455     1  0 14:42 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7522     1  0 14:42 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7559     1  0 14:43 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7587     1  0 14:48 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7595     1  0 14:49 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7604     1  0 14:49 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7643     1  0 14:49 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7666     1 97 15:03 tty1     00:00:21 -zsh
mbinary   7670  7666  0 15:03 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7699     4  0 15:03 tty1     00:00:00 ps -ef
➜  ~ sudo kill -9 1
➜  ~ ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Mar28 ?        00:00:00 /init ro
root         3     1  0 Mar28 tty1     00:00:00 /init ro
mbinary      4     3  0 Mar28 tty1     00:00:12 -zsh
mbinary     48     1  0 Mar28 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary     66     1  0 Mar28 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary    173     1  0 Mar29 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary    225     1  0 Mar29 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary    431     1  0 09:45 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
root      6845     1  0 09:53 tty2     00:00:00 /init ro
mbinary   6846  6845  0 09:53 tty2     00:00:04 -zsh
mbinary   7419  6846  0 10:03 tty2     00:00:00 python3
mbinary   7455     1  0 14:42 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7522     1  0 14:42 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7559     1  0 14:43 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7587     1  0 14:48 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7595     1  0 14:49 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7604     1  0 14:49 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7643     1  0 14:49 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7666     1 99 15:03 tty1     00:00:25 -zsh
mbinary   7670  7666  0 15:03 tty1     00:00:00 [awk] <defunct>
mbinary   7712     4  0 15:03 tty1     00:00:00 ps -ef
```

It doesn't work.

I found that the zombie processes `awk` occur after I use the command `z`.

Info:
Windows 10: 1809
WSL: Ubuntu 1804

Comment: Please add more details in your question. How those process are created? Which Windows 10 version? Does it happen with zsh only?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I didn't create awk process. It seems their parent process is `/init ro`. What's that?   My Windows 10 versison is 1809, and WSL is  Ubuntu 1804.

Comment: How those processes are created? Is there any complex theme in zsh?

Comment: @Biswapriyo The problem is that zsh costs too much CPU resource, which is unusual  after I upgrade Ubuntu 1604 to 1804. And I guess this is related to the zombie process `awk`. I don't know how they are created. Every time I open a shell, many zombie processes `awk` occur.  The theme is the default one.

Comment: I found that the zombie processes `awk` occur after I use the command `z`, a tool for changing directory in zsh.

Comment: Please add these details in your question not in comments. No need to reply this comment. You may remove your comments after adding the details in your question.

Answer (score 4):

I am running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (64-bit), Version 10.0.18362 and I still get rogue zsh processes. This function kills the rogue zsh processes.

`killzshs(){ps ax -o pid,command,ppid | grep '.*zsh.*\s1$' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9}`

Then call `killzshs` or put the function in your dotfiles.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed in Windows Version 10.0.18362.30. Details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3940)

Comment: Not really. I have `Version 10.0.19043.899` and also in the reference, there are some people saying that it did not solve really. In my case it seems something related to docker daemon, but I still didn't find a way to fix.